# Using MATLAB's `fmincon()` Solver for Linear Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, non-linear, convex-optimization

If I have a linear optimization problem to be solved, is it correct to use the FMINCON SOLVER? If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you have [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem you should use [`linprog()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html).
- If you have a linear parametric model, you may use Least Squares approach. Then you should use linear system solver. In case of linear constraints you should use [`lsqlin()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html).

The function `fmincon()` is designed for general smooth non linear problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but is it wrong to use fmincon for the linear problems?                      I actually had a closed form solution for the linear problem. But I just want to try with the fmincon. Is it technically correct to use a  nonlinear solver for a linear problem.

Comment: @Srikanth, It is not efficient but it will get you to the solution.

Comment: Because when I tried the fmincon on the linear the solution came out is different from the closed form solution I mean when I plot the freqz they looked completly different so. I am trying to know whether it is correct to use it or not.

Comment: @Srikanth, If you share the problem we'll be able to analyze it. If it is linear, it should converge to the same value of the objective.

Comment: @Srikanth, Could you please review my answer? If it fits you, could you mark it?